# How to change registry entries of different users?

Tags: c#, registry

I am working on a C# desktop application and i require so store some settings individually for each user in the HKCU section of the registry for each user. the requirements are such that these settings cannot be stored in a file or the database and registry is the best solution if possible..
Is it not possible to use impersonate method as we might not know passwords of all the users. however we will have the administrator access when running the exe.

is there a way that with administrator access we can access HKCU section for each user and populate the settings there

Comment: will your exe run on different accounts or just a single admin account will execute it?

Comment: You need Impersonate using a Admin account. If you don't know the user and pass of an admin account create one when installing.

Comment: Even if you did so, what if a new user logs on? It is usually best to let the application take care on first start: if the registry entries are missing, create them (maybe as copy of a template stored in HKLM).

Comment: I was able to access and update registry of users through NTUSER.dat file present in c:\users\[user_name]\. But the problem i am facing with this approach is that this folder is created on first login. so when i create a new user i cannot update their setting until they login once.

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin The exe will run on one administrator account only. but will manipulate registries of other users (admin and restricted users both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your scenario the first option was to impersonate the user, but as you are not willing to adopt it, now we have another option, obtain the user's SID, and then write the data under the KEY_USERS registry because this path contains all users in the machine.

Following is the utility function to write a value to specific user's registry key, obviously you need to know his/her username.

```
public static bool AddUserData(string userName, string key, string value)
{
   try
   {
        //Gets the SID of the desired user
        NTAccount f = new NTAccount(userName);
        SecurityIdentifier s = (SecurityIdentifier)f.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
        string sid = s.ToString();

        //Define the path to the subkey
        string path = @"SOFTWARE\Console\DefaultConfig";

        //try to open the path
        var reg = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", sid, path), true);
        if (reg == null)
        {
            //if not exists create that path for that user
            reg = Registry.Users.CreateSubKey(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", sid, path));
        }

        //set value against key
        reg.SetValue(key, value);
        return true;
    }
   catch
   {
       return false;
   }
}
```

feel free to check documentation of the `Registry` class so that you will learn better to read the value back, this is just starting direction for you, Also I have not tested the code but I am pretty sure this will help you a lot. The admin access for the program is must for this code to work, otherwise you are left with impersonation.

Comment: Yes, this works, also found another solution to add the values in the default user profile and when whenever a new user is created their registry automatically gets those values.[link]https://superuser.com/questions/1285378/apply-registry-tweak-to-newly-created-users